# SQL query with multiple criteria in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to query into a database, but I have to insert multiple conditions.

Fake example:

#of books in the library currently,
Of those books, count how many are overdue,
Of those books, count how many have an author that start with the letter 'a'.

Note: Of those books = #of books in the library currently

How can I approach this?

I tried making a bunch of small queries and storing them in variables.

Comment: `select * from books where datedue < getdate() and author like 'a%';`

Comment: Please clarify your question with a [mre] (Please actually read the link, it really will help you.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are expecting to do the following tasks:

- Number of books in the library currently.
- Of those books, which ones are overdue.
- Of those books, which ones have an author that starts with the letter 'A'.

```
WITH books_in_library AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM books 
    WHERE status = 'in_library'
),
overdue_books AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM books_in_library 
    WHERE due_date < GETDATE()
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books_in_library) AS TotalInLibrary,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM overdue_books) AS TotalOverdue,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(author_name, 1) IN ('a', 'A') THEN 1 END) AS TotalOverdueWithAuthorA
FROM overdue_books;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It's a little more complicated because I need a COUNT(*) for each condition: "SELECT (number of books, number of overdue books, number of books with authors 'a') FROM library".  Is it possible to do this in one query?

Comment: Edited my answer. Chcek if this is what you're expecting

Comment: Far too complicated, just use one single query with a `conditional count`. Search for that term,. there are many good explanations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional aggregation. This is more efficient in this case as it only requires a single scan of the base table.

```sql
SELECT
  TotalBooks         = COUNT(*),
  InLibrary          = COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'in_library' THEN 1 END),
  TakenOutAndOverdue = COUNT(CASE WHEN status <> 'in_library' AND due_date < GETDATE() THEN 1 END),
  Author StartsWithA = COUNT(CASE WHEN author_name LIKE 'A%' THEN 1 END)
FROM books;
```